# How to convert the ASP code snippet to PHP?

Tags: php

```
function isChongHao(ary,i,j)
    if ary(i-1,j)<>0 or ary(i+1,j) then
        isChongHao=true
        exit function
    end if
    isChongHao=false
end function
```

Comment: what is the input and intended output?

Answer (score 4):

```
function isChongHao($ary, $i, $j) {
  if($ary[$i-1][$j] != 0 || $ary[$i+1][$j]) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

--I suppose $ary contains a name of a function.--

Ooops, strike that: Joel thanks, I totally missed the fact that it was vbscript!!! O.o
Now maybe it is better...

Comment: No, vbscript (asp) uses parentheses for array subscripts and does not support passing functions as first class objects at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
function isChongHao($ary, $i, $j)
{
    return ($ary[$i-1][$j] || $ary[$i+1][$j]);
 }
```

You should probably check to ensure those indexes are set in the array beforehand, though, with an isset() call.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ary is an array

```
function isChongHao($ary,$i,$j) {
    return (($ary[$i-1][$j] || $ary[$i+1][$j]) ? true : false);
}
```

Assuming ary is a function

```
function isChongHao($ary,$i,$j) {
    return (($ary($i-1,$j) || $ary($i+1,$j)) ? true : false);
}
```